# words don't break correctly

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

In a block I have a text. I have some trouble with the linefeedtreatment.

```
<fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
</fo:block>
```

**The text Shows like this:**

Master II Phase 1, Pha-

se 2, Phase 3

**Must look like this:**

Master II Phase 1,

Phase 2, Phase 3

I've tried "Keep-together.within-line" and "linefeed-treatment" but without any result.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have hyphenation enabled when you don't want it to be.  Presumably your FO contains `hyphenate="true"` on some ancestor FO.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#hyphenate

Add `hyphenate="false"` to the `fo:block` to disable hyphenation of the text in the block.

The other possibility is that you have soft-hyphen characters in your text.  If `hyphenate="false"` doesn't solve the problem, please edit your question to add the XML for the `text` element that has the problem.